# Listing all databases, all tables, and all columns on a SQL Server instance

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to write a query that for a single SQL Server instance, lists all columns in all tables in all databases on the server instance.  I have found examples that list all columns in all tables but you have to know the database name.  I have found examples that list databases on a SQL Server instance but not the tables in the databases.  Now I am trying to find something that combines the two, but I am not having much luck.

Would anyone know if such a thing exists or is it a manual process to bridge the gap?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic query. I did not find any other way.

```
declare @str varchar(max) = ''
;with dbs as (
select *
from sys.databases
where dbs.name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
)
select @str = @str + 'select ''' + dbs.name + ''', tbl.name, col.name from ' + 
    dbs.name + '.sys.tables tbl inner join ' + 
    dbs.name + '.sys.columns col ON col.object_id = tbl.object_id; '
from dbs

print @str
exec(@str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and feed back with comments.

The requirement was to find out one particular table from all the database. This was not possible by visual inspection as it might take lots of time and human error was possible. She was aware of the system view sys.tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE name LIKE '%Address%'
```

The limitation of query mentioned above is that it only searches in one database and user has to keep on changing database manually and run the query again. I wrote down following quick script which looks into all the database on the server and provides the database name, schema name and table containing searched word in its name.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase
@TableName VARCHAR(256)

AS
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @getDBName CURSOR
SET @getDBName = CURSOR FOR

SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
CREATE TABLE #TmpTable (DBName VARCHAR(256),
SchemaName VARCHAR(256),
TableName VARCHAR(256))
OPEN @getDBName
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @varSQL = 'USE ' + @DBName + ';
INSERT INTO #TmpTable
SELECT '''+ @DBName + ''' AS DBName,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE ''%' + @TableName + '%'''
EXEC (@varSQL)
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
END
CLOSE @getDBName
DEALLOCATE @getDBName
SELECT *
FROM #TmpTable
DROP TABLE #TmpTable
GO

EXEC usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase 'Address'
GO
```